# PHP - how to add to variable NULL value and save in into database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I am trying set variable to `NULL`:

```
$q = NULL.",";
$q .= 'abc';
```

and save in to database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (col_a, col_b) VALUES (".$q.")")
```

But this generates error message:

```
INSERT INTO table (col_a, col_b) VALUES (,'abc')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ','abc')' at line 2
```

How to save `NULL` into database from variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get rid of the column where you want its value to be null, eg

```
$q = 'abc';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (col_b) VALUES ($q)")
```

or if value is dynamic, the only problem with your current code is that you haven't include `NULL` in your string,

```
$q = "NULL,";
$q .= "'abc'";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (col_a, col_b) VALUES ($q)")
```

the your code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to learn how to prevent from it.

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You're concatenating NULL and trying to parse it, which in the statement, would actually read:

, abc

Instead of the expected

NULL, abc

So just write a literal "NULL" in your statement.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the literal, unquoted string inside the query:

```
$q = "NULL,";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = "NULL,";
$q .= '"abc"';
```

Gives you `NULL,"abc"` which you can include in your query.

The error you posted couldn't have come from the code in the question.. where did the quotes around `abc` come from? You need to enclose it in quotes inside the quotes for the php variable for them to show up in the SQL too.